# Install RPMs on the host from inside a kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, rpm, k3s, docker-privileged

Is there a way to run a privileged pod that I can use to install RPMs and packages on the host where the pod is running?

Thanks!

If I just run privileged pod, exec into it and would try to run the command:

```
rpm -i <package.rpm>
```

I would install that RPM in the pod itself, not on the physical machine.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You would have to use `hostPath` volumes to mount the host file system. More information can be found here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Pod that connects to the Node where it "runs" goes against the containerization pattern; take a look at the images below this link: https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container/

However you can do something, perhaps creating a bridge as done here: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/issues/1200#issuecomment-568735188